# Is there a way to do COMMENT ON DATABASE current_database() IS '...' in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way I can set the comment on the currently connected database of an arbitrary name?

Without relying on custom functions or extensions I would like to do something like:

`COMMENT ON DATABASE current_database()::regclass IS 'my comment';`

Comment: No, that is currently not possible. There is [a patch](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAFjFpRe0JVVVL5ZnNH226NPmgEBRnhQq6uxKr23sr7z_%2BHdPfQ%40mail.gmail.com#CAFjFpRe0JVVVL5ZnNH226NPmgEBRnhQq6uxKr23sr7z_+HdPfQ@mail.gmail.com) pending for that but it seems it did not make it into Postgres 10 so I guess you'll have to rely on a custom function until Postgres 11 is released

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically execute a prepared statement.

```
DO LANGUAGE PLPGSQL $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE FORMAT('COMMENT ON DATABASE %I IS %L', current_database(), 'my comment');
END;
$$;
```

You can wrap it in an anonymous code block of PL/pgSQL. No custom functions or extensions necessary.